# guild.get_member returns None when getting discord.Member object using an ID

Tags: python, discord.py

What I have is a command that assigns a role. `;assigntestrole <@user>`. I've tried multiple different ways of getting a member object including `client.fetch_user`, getting the object through a guild and other stuff. I keep getting `NoneType` objects. Here's my code so far:

```
import discord
client = discord.Client()
TOKEN = 'MYTOKEN'
prefix = ';'

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if str(message.content)[0] != prefix:
        return

    user = str(message.content).split(' ')[1]
    guild = client.get_guild(message.guild.id)
    user_obj = guild.get_member(int(user[2:-1]))
    print(user_obj)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

The output I'm getting is `None` no matter which method I use (tried `client.fetch_member(int(user[2:-1]))`, `discord.utils.get(message.guild.members, id=int(user[2:-1])` and others). Any ideas as to what might be causing such behavior?

Comment: it's `None` because it couldn't get the member. Have you checked, what `user[2:1]` returns?

Comment: yup, it returns the id exactly. I even tried putting `message.author.id` in instead of `int(user[2:-1])`, still returns `None` @puncher

Comment: Is that user in the guild? Also you might want to try it with `members` intent enabled (although I'm pretty sure you should be able to `get_member` without the intent, try it anyway). Try typing `<@12345>` where the `12345` is the `int(user[2:-1])` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, my suspicion was correct. In order for `get_member` to work, it actually does require the members intent. It's hidden deep inside the docs [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=intents#discord.Intents.members)

> Whether guild member related events are enabled.
>
> This also corresponds to the following attributes and classes in terms of cache:
>
> ...
> `Guild.get_member()`

Enable the `members` intent and it will be solved.

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
#intents.message_content = True  # if you need this
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Note that [`fetch_member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=intents#discord.Guild.fetch_member) can still be used without that intent if you really don't want it, but it costs an extra API call.